# Verify that the leaf certificate was signed by the sub-CA certificate

Tags: java, certificate, ca

I have the Apple Root CA - G3 root Certificate and I need to validate the chain of trust. I need to verify that the leaf certificate was signed by the sub-CA certificate.

How can I do this with Java?

Comment: Questions asking for tutorials or other offsite resources are considered off topic for Stack Overflow so they typically attract downvotes and close votes (1 at the time of writing), so I've removed that part of your question. This may still be too broad, but I think there's a plausibly useful question here so I'll leave *that* decision to people that know better than I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet

```
X509Certificate certificate =...
X509Certificate intermediate = ...
try{
    certificate.verify(intermediate.getPublicKey());
        //Verification ok.    intermediate  is the issuer
    } catch (Exception e){}
}
```