# Validate Certificate against trusted certificate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, certificate

I want to validate a certificate coming in request against my trusted certificate having root and intermediate CA signer. How it can be achieved in java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate](https://www.thomasvitale.com/https-spring-boot-ssl-certificate/)

Comment: Hi Thank you for response but my requirement is not to enable ssl, but to validate certificate in java against one that I have.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42291148/6371459) to validate a single certificate and  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527750/6371459)to validate a certification chain